# How do tag wikis work?

Tags: support, tags, community-wiki, editing

So I recently received the privilege to add tags but I can't find anything on the privileges list that mentions when I'm able to update tag wikis?  When does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should be able to propose edits now, but they will need to be approved by someone with 1500+ reputation.

Comment: turns out my new tag needed approved before I could edit it. Hence the confusion :D